# Requests package and API documentation

Tags: python, api, python-requests, documentation

I'm having trouble understanding where to add parameters defined by API documentation. Take BeeBole's [documentation](https://beebole.com/timesheet-api/#absence) for example, which specifies that to get an absence by ID, the following request is required:

```
    {
"service": "absence.get",
"id": "absence_id"
}
```

They provide only one URL in the documentation:

> BeeBole is accepting HTTP POST resquests in a json-doc format to the following URL:
>   https://beebole-apps.com/api/v2

How would this be implemented in the context of Python requests? The following code I've tried returns 404:

```
import requests

payload = {
    "service": "absence.get",
    "id": "absence_id"
}

auth = {
    "username": "API_token",
    "password": "x"
}

url = "https://beebole-apps.com/api/v2"

req = requests.get(url, params=payload, auth=auth).json()
```

Comment: if it's 404, you may need to double check the url you're using

Comment: Its the only URL listed in their documentation, are you sure its not anything to do with my parameters?

Comment: They expect a JSON document, but you are sending a URL query instead.

Comment: hmm are you sure you need the `auth` keywork arg? that doesn't go in the `headers`?

Comment: I'll probably use their example of including it in the URL so thanks for picking this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BeeBole is accepting HTTP POST resquests in a json-doc format to the following URL: https://beebole-apps.com/api/v2

The JSON document format here is the part you missed; you need to pass the information as a JSON encoded *body* of the request. The `params` argument you used only sets the URL query string (the `?...` part in a URL).

Use

```
import requests

payload = {
    "service": "absence.get",
    "id": "absence_id"
}

auth = ("API_token", "x")    
url = "https://beebole-apps.com/api/v2"

req = requests.get(url, json=payload, auth=auth).json()
```

The `json=` part ensures that the `payload` dictionary is encoded to JSON and sent as a POST body. This also sets the `Content-Type` header of the request.

I've also updated the [API authentication](https://beebole.com/timesheet-api/#authentication), all that the `auth` keyword needs here is a tuple of the username and password. See the [*Basic Authentication* section](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/#basic-authentication).

You may want to wait with calling `.json()` on the response; check if the response was successful first:

```
req = requests.get(url, json=payload, auth=auth)
if not req.ok:
    print('Request not OK, status:', req.status_code, req.reason)
    if req.content:
        print(req.text)
else:
    data = req.json()
    if data['status'] == 'error':
        print('Request error:', data['message'])
```

This uses the [documented error responses](https://beebole.com/timesheet-api/#response).

Comment: Is the `.json()` right? I haven't seen a request like that before

Comment: @SuperStew: the response has a `.json()` method, so yes, provided the response is a 200 success response then that will work.

Answer (score 0):

From the site documentation it would appear that this particular vendor has chosen an unusual API. Most people use different endpoints to implement different operations, but BeeBole appears to implement everything off the one endpoint, and then selects the operation by examining the `"service"` key in the request data.

Try

```
response - request.post('https://beebole-apps.com/api/v2',
                        json={"service": "company.list"},
                        headers={"authorization": TOKEN)
```

From the documentation I can't guarantee that will put the request in the right format, but at least if it doesn't work it should give you some clue as to how to proceed. Establishing the correct value of `TOKEN` is described under "Authorization" in the BeeBole documentation.

It's an unusual way to offer an API, but it seems workable.